# ReturnUrl in RouteConfig.Cs not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

In my MVC project I Use this code in RouteConfig.Cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Signin",
                url: "login/{ReturnUrl}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Signin", ReturnUrl = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

but url not workin well when i'm browsing the signin page from another page for example:

localhost:43773/account/signin?ReturnUrl=anotherpage

i expect : localhost:43773/login/anotherpage

how can i fix this?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot. This is because both are considered equivalents.

Comment: I Edit my Post, I Expect : localhost:43773/account/login/anotherpage

Comment: `localhost:43773/account/signin?ReturnUrl=anotherpage` does not match that route. The route you have specified starts with "login/" and has one paramater

Comment: I Edit My Post, I Expected : localhost:43773/login/anotherpage

Comment: This is wrong approach, you will loose your query string values, usually ReturnUrl encodes query string values that must be preserved after redirect. Do you have plan to forward query strings correctly?

Comment: In my Action I use this code: public ActionResult SignIn(string ReturnUrl){}, Do you mean the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are expecting. But ASP.NET MVC does NOT generate URLs based on the route(s) you define. That would be both unnecessary and would incur  an overhead.

If it is really important for you to have a URL like localhost:43773/account/login/anotherpage, then you could look into [IIS URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Here is an example of how you can achieve what you want to do

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Standardize Log In Url" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^account/signin?ReturnUrl=([0-9a-z]+)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="account/login/{R:1}" />
        </rule> 
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**NOTE** This solution is untested, so you may need to make some modifications to it.

Comment: thanx Parth for your answer, I Expected : localhost:43773/login/anotherpage and I Edited My Post, how can i fix this?